How to Properly Colorize PDF Figures in LaTeX: Fill Color and Transparency Problems
I've been trying to include a monochromatic PDF vector figure in my LaTeX document and change its fill color directly within LaTeX, without using any external tools. I found two main solutions:

Sol1: Setting the PDF color space to RGB and using the decodearray option in \includegraphics. Unfortunately, this method didn't work for me.
Sol2: Using TikZ pictures. This method gave me better results but still isn't perfect.

I'm running into two main problems with the TikZ method:

Inconsistent Fill Color: Even though I used the same color for the top and bottom borders of the hlines in tblr, the colors of the figure and the \hline don’t look the same.
Unwanted Background: The figure has a white background behind it, even though the original figure is black on a transparent background. I set fill=transparent!0 in the TikZ picture, but it didn’t fix the issue.

Any suggestions on how to resolve these issues?

Original figure is black (you can download it from here: "left_logo.pdf"). Shown on the right side of the attached image.
Here’s the LaTeX code I’m using:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=left]
  \node [fill=transparent!0,draw=none]
  {\includegraphics[width=2.05cm,height=2cm]{./Resources/Figures/left_logo}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{titlepage}

  \pagecolor{gray} 
  \begin{tblr}{
    width=\textwidth,
    colspec = {Q[c,2.65cm]X[c]Q[c,2.65cm]},
    rowspec = {Q[b]},
    hlines={1pt, MidnightBlue},
    measure=vbox}
      \fbox{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
          outer sep=0pt,
          inner sep=0pt,
          baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \node[left color=MidnightBlue,right color=MidnightBlue,minimum width=2.16cm,minimum height=1.85cm]{};
            \path[scope fading=left,fit fading=false];
            \node[fill=transparent!0,minimum width=2.16cm+1mm,minimum height=1.85cm+1mm]{};
        \end{tikzpicture}}
      &{
        \textcolor{MidnightBlue}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \\
        \textcolor{MidnightBlue}{Proin non mauris maximus, pretium} \\
        \textcolor{MidnightBlue}{In convallis eros convallis nunc} \\
        \textcolor{MidnightBlue}{Integer eleifend sit amet risus} \\
        \textcolor{MidnightBlue}{Fusce vulputate ac felis et}
      }&
      \fbox{\includegraphics[width=2.05cm,height=2cm]{./Resources/Figures/left_logo}}
  \end{tblr}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}

Edit
I forgot to mention that I'm compiling my document with LuaLaTeX.

You could unset the color of the star so that the included pdf will inherit the colour of the surrounding text.
Following the guide from Changing color in an eps file from within LaTeX one can create the following pdf:
https://github.com/samcarter/shared/blob/main/TeXse/unset.pdf
(the colour was commented out in l.9)
... and then use it like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth} 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

  \pagecolor{gray} 
  \begin{tblr}{
    width=\textwidth,
    colspec = {Q[c,2.65cm]X[c]Q[c,2.65cm]},
    rowspec = {Q[b]},
    hlines={1pt, MidnightBlue},
    measure=vbox}
      \fbox{\color{MidnightBlue}\includegraphics[width=2.05cm,height=2cm]{unset}}
      &{
        \textcolor{MidnightBlue}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \\
        \textcolor{MidnightBlue}{Proin non mauris maximus, pretium} \\
        \textcolor{MidnightBlue}{In convallis eros convallis nunc} \\
        \textcolor{MidnightBlue}{Integer eleifend sit amet risus} \\
        \textcolor{MidnightBlue}{Fusce vulputate ac felis et}
      }&
      \fbox{\includegraphics[width=2.05cm,height=2cm]{left_logo}}
  \end{tblr}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}



Thanks for your help; this is working great with pdftex. However, when switching to LuaLaTeX, I've run into an error: error: (file ./Figures/unset.pdf) (pdf inclusion): reading image failed. Any suggestions on resolving this? It's essential for me to use LuaLaTeX, as some other parts of my document don't function with pdftex. @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz

Works fine for me with lualatex as well

What, in your opinion, could be causing the compilation with LuaLaTeX to fail on my computer? see @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz

@Mycroft_47 If you'd use the very same code as in my question and then show the .log file, I could compare them

Yeah, I used the code you provided. Here's the log of my compilation . @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz

This looks like the console output. Can you show the .log file?

Also the path to the image seems to be different. can you try in the same folder as the .tex file?

Yeah you are right I just copied the log displayed in the console. Do you know where I can locate the actual .log file? @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz

It should be in the same folder as your .tex file

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I get a warning from pdftex that the file is damaged (broken xref table) and lualatex fails completly.

I moved the figure to the same level as the .tex file, but it still didn't work. see

@UlrikeFischer mmm, I just tried again with pdflatex no problems in the .log file. Maybe github mangles the file somehow. May I sent you the original file?

here's my .log file @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz sure. But the message is only on the terminal, not in the log.

@UlrikeFischer Oh! I'll check the terminal then.

@UlrikeFischer Checked my terminal for both pdflatex and lualatex, no problems there. That's curious!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the real file is okay, the github file has a changed marker below the version and that adds three bytes and so breaks the xref.

pdfTex log

@UlrikeFischer Thank you so much for checking! I'll find a better way to upload the pdf

@Mycroft_47 I'll upload to somewhere else and will ping you

I appreciate it, thanks. @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz

@Mycroft_47 Would you mind to test if https://github.com/samcarter/shared/blob/main/TeXse/unset.pdf works?

It did work thanks! I'm curious to know what was the problem & how you fixed it. @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz

@Mycroft_47 The problem seems to have been that when uploading the file as gist, github changed something in the file which is always risky in pdfs. I uploaded it again in a traditional github repository instead of gist which seems to avoid the problem.

Thank you very much for the answer and the explanation. @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz

@Mycroft_47 It was a real life demonstration that https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119210/changing-color-in-an-eps-file-from-within-latex/119380#119380 is absolutely correct to say one needs to be careful when unsetting the colour :) Sorry for the trouble!

Isn't there a way to automate this process of unsetting colors? Yesterday, I attempted to do it manually and encountered the same issue. Then, I thought to myself that I should switch back to using the TikZ method I initially employed. @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz

@Mycroft_47 Theoretically, inkscape can also unset colours and I remember using this in the past, but when I tried it today, it didn't work (maybe a problem with inkscape 1.3?) If one could get this to work, one might be able to script it.

@Mycroft_47 Different approach: if the image is relatively simple, you could convert it to svg and then use the svg path in tikz

May I ask you a question? After checking the answer, I found that this process involves three main steps: uncompressing the PDF, identifying/deleting the color operators, and then compressing the PDF. My question is about the identification step. Is there a general rule to identify these color operators, and can we use regular expressions for this, or is it more complex due to how color operators are stored inside PDFs? @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz

@Mycroft_47 For this easy example, my identification technique was "find the part with three numbers". For more complicate images, I would use an pdf editor like inkscape to change the colour into something recognisable (0.314 0.314 0.314 or whatever you like) and then search for these numbers

Great! I actually used Inkscape to create the star vector in the example above, this piece of information can simplify the manual identification process. Another question I have is whether the color space matters when exporting figures to PDF. For example, if I use the CMYK color space, will this method still work, or should I always use RGB as stated here? @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz

@Mycroft_47 No idea
